# A List of all the prayers a Muslim can pray?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

I want to be a better Muslim by praying more than I should. So I searched on the internet to see what ALL the Islam prayers are. Now I am confused. Can someone please tell me what these prayers are and how to pray them:

- fard
- wajib
- sunnat
- nafil
- nafilah
- witr
- tahajjud
- eid adha
- eid fitr
- taraweeh
- namaz
- jumuah
- salat al-layl
- Salat istikhara
- Funeral salat
- Salatul Shaf’a
- Salat of Ja’far e Tayyar (as)
- Salaat -e-Gufaila
- Namaz/Salaat of Masoomeen(Ahlulbayt -as)
- Salat Tawaf of the Ka‘bah
- Salat-i-Hajjat
- a Thanksgiving Prayer

Are there any more prayers that I should be aware of?

Thank you.

[Source1](https://sufism.org/salaat/salaat-times-2)

[Source2](https://www.alislam.org/library/book/salat/types-of-prayers-and-number-of-rakats/)

[Source3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prayers#Islamic_prayers)

Comment: Some of the listed prayers have no backup or are considered to be based on non authentic sources. Also you are mixing sunni and shi'a traditions as it seems. **List questions hardly fit in our model**. Beside this you don't need to perform more nafl prayers to be a good Muslim it is better to do a deed  you might be able to perform when you are much older the prophet () gave this advice to 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr as he was young (he decided to pray the night prayer every night) and when he became old he regretted not following it as his health had gone and he found hardship to go on like before.